# Сравнение списка и numpy по скорости создания. Numpy проиграл

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, range

Сделал два списка: обычный и numpy-ский. Ожидал, как и положено, что numpy будет в 10 раз быстрее, но получилось наоборот. Хочу посоветоваться, может кто, что подскажет.
Работаю на Ubunte 16.04, python 3.6, Jupyter Notebook.[image: Замер времени]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[range(start, stop[, step])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) возвращает объект типа `range`, а не список:

> The advantage of the range type over a regular list or tuple is that a
>   `range` object will always take the same (small) amount of memory, no
>   matter the size of the range it represents (as it only stores the
>   `start`, `stop` and `step` values, calculating individual items and
>   subranges as needed).

Чтобы получить полноценный список надо вызвать конструктор `list(range(...))`:

```
In [1]: %timeit np.arange(0, 1000)
4.7 µs ± 20.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [2]: %timeit list(range(0, 1000))
44.5 µs ± 9.76 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```